# Drawing a diagram of a one-bit adder

Tags: diagram

How can I draw a diagram of the one-bit adder (full, including the transfer) built with the smallest possible number of logic gates?

Comment: Pressing ctrl-M should bring up a schematic editor, which is quite easy to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder)

[image: Schematic]

It's really straight from the truth table and appropriate mapping. I do recall that there is a bit of a trick in recognizing the use of an XOR gate though.

Comment: I think OP was asking for a reduction method, that this answer does not explain at all.

Comment: If so that wasn't very clear to me. It seemed to be a question regarding both drawing and how to build the adder with the smallest number of components.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after the smallest number of logic gates, sherrellbc's answer looks to be correct. If you're looking for the smallest number of transistors or a faster/better implementation there're plenty of options [here.](https://www.google.com/search?q=1%20bit%20adder%20cmos&num=50&espv=2&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=DWOoU6LwDsH7oATI4IKYCA&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1422&bih=1043&dpr=0.9)

Here's one for example:
[image]